# How to accept value from textctrl in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Here is a python pgm. It contains a text ctrl and a button. Please help me to modify so that on pressing the button I need the string user entered in textctrl to be stored to a variable.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#Boa:Frame:Frame1

import wx

def create(parent):
    return Frame1(parent)

[wxID_FRAME1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, wxID_FRAME1TEXT1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(4)]

class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
        # generated method, don't edit
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_FRAME1, name='', parent=prnt,
              pos=wx.Point(249, 224), size=wx.Size(683, 445),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame1')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(683, 445))

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(id=wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, name='panel1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(683, 445),
              style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.text1 = wx.TextCtrl(id=wxID_FRAME1TEXT1, name=u'text1',
              parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(268, 139), size=wx.Size(103, 25),
              style=0, value=u'enter')

        self.button1 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, label=u'click',
              name='button1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(279, 272),
              size=wx.Size(85, 27), style=0)
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

    def OnButton1Button(self, event):
        event.Skip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a method attached to a wxTextCtrl object called [getValue](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxtextctrl.html#wxtextctrlgetvalue), so in OnButton1Button(), you call

```
var = self.text1.GetValue()
```

And then do what you want with `var` afterwards.

Comment: is'nt it var = self.text1.GetValue()  ?? case significant? but after doing this when i add "print var"  the string does not print.

Comment: I've not worked with the Python version of wxWidgets, just the C++ version, but upon [further investigation](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html#GetValue) It is in-fact GetValue(), not getValue(). My only other suggestion would to change the name of the variable to something like str or myVar1 to make sure var isn't a reserved word in python.